# Error when splitting Data into Test and Training set(Sampling Without Replacement)

Tags: r, dataframe, sampling

Hi I am splitting my set  Adata1 into test and training by random sampling . I keep getting this error when I make my test set:

> test = Adata1[-(Training),]
>       Error in x[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
>       2: In Ops.ordered(left) : '-' is not meaningful for ordered factors
>       3: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
>       4: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
>       5: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

Here is my Code :

```
set.seed(50000)
size = ceiling(0.8*nrow(Adata1))
Training = Adata1[sample(NROW(Adata1),size,replace = FALSE ),]
library(dplyr)
test = Adata1[-Training,] ----The error appears here
```

Comment: Hoe does `Training` looks like once you created is? Looks like you sample `Adata1` and then you try to re-select stuff in `Adata1` from what you have in training

Comment: I create the Training set from Adata1 and then I try remove all those entries from Adata1 to create the test set